# Deadlock caused by a garbage collection?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, deadlock, dump

This issue has been troubling me for a long while and so far I haven't managed to find what could be causing it. After running fine for days or even weeks, the application suddenly starts to consume all the CPU available for no apparent reason. There are no suspicious runaway threads as far as I can tell. The only solution, for now, is to restart the application. The memory usage is stable throughout.

Here is the analysis of a dump file that was created just before killing the process when it was at 99% CPU:
http://5.45.73.43/tmp/dump_analysis.mht

It's done with the Debug Diagnostic Tool and need to be opened with Internet Explorer (sorry!).

As you can see, it looks like there's many threads that are stuck while waiting for the GC to finish, while the thread that called for GC is stuck as well. I am not sure why that would trigger a high CPU usage, though. Could it be something unrelated to GC? But then it does seem that it is the culprit...

Comment: just a guess, as your question does not warrant much more, maybe an infinite loop in destructor/finalizer?

Comment: Good point, but neither are used in the application...

Comment: also, deadlocks typically appear as application hang without processor usage, which in turn is most often caused by infinite loops

Comment: That's the thing, I couldn't find any infinite loops by looking at the dump file. This is seriously confusing. Have you had a time to check the dump analysis report by any chance?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Utils.CascadingRandom().  Lots of threads are calling it, do keep in mind that the Random class is not thread-safe.

Comment: Here's the code from it: http://pastie.org/10716313